# How to get a Spinner with non cyclic behaviour? (stop on max value)

Tags: java, widget, swt, spinner, cyclic

I have a Spinner, which behaviour is cyclic by default:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(composite, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER);
spinner.setMaximum(5);
```

The objective is that when the user press the next button on 5, the 5 must not change to 0, and when the user is on 0 and press the previous button, the 0 must not change to 5.

Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SWT.WRAP` style specifies that the value wraps from the maximum to the minimum, so just leave out that style:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(composite, SWT.BORDER);
spinner.setMaximum(5);
```

Comment: I haven't ever seen anything that tries to do a long click.

Comment: ok but it's not a long click, it must repeat the event each 100 milliseconds (for example) until the click is ended

Comment: Yes, but that just makes it even more complicated since it would have to be done with mouse listeners, timers and simulated clicks.

Comment: ok thanks @greg-449 one more think, do you know if it's possible to visualize a spinner without the arrows? only the field? thank you. Or with horizontal arrows, previous arrow in the left of the field and next arrow in the right of the field. Can't find none of the two possibilities on the documentation of Spinner, so only way I know to achieve that is to make it with my own buttons and fields and not with spinner

Comment: Spinner has no customization for the arrow positions.